# Get a Vue.js file into my apps controller and move it into public path

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js

I'm working with laravel and Vuejs to create a form, I succeed to download files and save them as files but I don't know how to stock them into my public path . I have that in my console VueJs :

```
files: Array[3]
       0: File
       1: File
       2: File
```

Hi !

I'm working with laravel and Vuejs to create a form, I succeed to download files and save them as files but I don't know how to stock them into my public path . I have that in my console VueJs :
Capture d’écran 2017-10-19 à 12.37.17

This is my function :

```
    uploadFiles: function () {
      var files = this.$refs.file_input.files;
      var data = new FormData();
      data.append('input_name[]', files[0]);
      this.form.image =files[0].name;
      for (var i = 1; i< files.length; i++) {
       data.append('input_name[]', files[i]);
       this.form.image =this.form.image+ ',' + files[i].name;

     }
     this.form.files = data.getAll('input_name[]');





   },
```

Do you have any idea what have I to add to save it  ? I tried this : 
`this.$http.post('/images/uploads', files[i])` but it didn't work. Do you have any idea ?

Anyone?

Comment: So what actual error message are you getting? If you are not getting any error message please look where your file has ended up. Most likely you simply need to use your public `disk`.

Comment: Hi thank you for your answer, it just does not save it into my public path. I think it's the "request('files') as $file" I would like to transform tho get all my files which I get thanks to a vuejs.

Comment: I have this error :   ( POST http://oip.dev/store 500 (Internal Server Error))